# Unknown XML error

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read in some XML data but I'm getting an error I've never spotted before. Can anyone shed some light on this?

The error:

> Screen name: System.Xml.Linq.Extensions+c__Iterator5
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
> HV_ReadSettingsFile:Update() (at Assets/_scripts/HV_ReadSettingsFile.cs:64)

Here is my code reading in the XML and is ultimately generating the error:

```
   var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\Test.xml");
        var screen = xdoc.Descendants("Screen");
              

        foreach (var Screen in screen)
        {
            HV_Screen _screen = new HV_Screen();
            _screen.Name = Convert.ToString(Screen.Descendants("Name").Attributes("Name"));
              

            Debug.Log("Screen name: " + _screen.Name);
        }
```

And my XML sheet:

```
<Settings>
  <Display_Settings>
    <Screen>
      <Name Name="Screen" />
      <ScreenTag Tag="Screen Tag" />
      <LocalPosition X="12" Y="81" Z="28" />
      <Width Width="54" />
      <Height Height="912" />
    </Screen>
     <Screen>
      <Name Name="Screen" />
      <ScreenTag Tag="Screen Tag" />
      <LocalPosition X="32" Y="21" Z="28" />
      <Width Width="54" />
      <Height Height="912" />
    </Screen>
  </Display_Settings>
</Settings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error. That's logging exactly what you've asked for. You've asked for all the `Name` attributes in all the `Name` elements... but then you're trying to log that *sequence* as a single value.

I think you want:

```
var screens = xdoc.Descendants("Screen");
foreach (var screen in screens)
{
    HV_Screen _screen = new HV_Screen();
    _screen.Name = (string) screen.Element("Name").Attribute("Name");

    Debug.Log("Screen name: " + _screen.Name);
}
```

This is now looking for *one* element and *one* attribute per `Screen` element. Note that I've changed the variable names to follow normal .NET conventions, other than `_screen` as I don't know what `HV_Screen` is meant to be.

It's not really clear why you've got separate elements for `Width`, `Height` and `Name`, each with an attribute matching the element name - and `ScreenTag` nearly doing so. If the XML is under your control, you might consider either:

```
<Screen Name="Screen" Width="54" Height="912" Tag="Screen Tag">
  <LocalPosition X="12" Y="81" Z="28" />
</Screen>
```

or perhaps:

```
<Screen>
  <Name>Screen</Name>
  <ScreenTag>Screen Tag</ScreenTag>
  <LocalPosition X="12" Y="81" Z="28" />
  <Width>54</Width>
  <Height>912</Height>
</Screen>
```

Also, if you're trying to build a collection of `HV_Screen` items, you probably want to use a query rather than a `foreach` loop - but it's not clear what you're actually trying to do beyond logging debug information at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\test.xml");

        List<string> lstScreen = xdoc.Descendants("Screen").Select(x => x.Element("Name").Attribute("Name").Value).ToList();

        foreach (string name in lstScreen)
        {
          ...
```

I hope help you!!